# How to get a vertice list from a .dae or .mesh file

Tags: ros, dae, planning-scene, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an easy way to have a vertice list from a .dae or .mesh file for importing into a planning scene as a CollisionObject?

If I use the arm_navigation_msgs::Shape::MESH type, I have to provide a vertice list, but I don't know if I have to read and extract vertices or if there is existing functions/methods for that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49634/how-to-get-a-vertice-list-from-a-.dae-or-.mesh-file/) by [Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3715/panda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to look at this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/11408/ros-electric-arm-navigation-programmatically-adding-collision-object/

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3715/panda/) on 2012-12-03**:
Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for. I searched for some time but didn't find that one.